# Pass function handle

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the following problem in matlab. I have a function which is defined by 5 parameters and 4 variables which are input as data. I define it as such:

`g = @(b)((b(4)*(b(2)*x(:,1) + b(3)*x(:,2) + 1)) + b(5)*x(:,3)*x(:,4).^b(1));`

I then want to find the values of the parameter which minimize the error in this function, which I define as such:

`sum_res = @(b)(y-g)'*(y-g);
    [beta_opt,fval] = fminsearch(sum_res,[1,1]);`

I get the following error message:

```
Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Error in @(b)(y-g)'*(y-g)


Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is spot on; `g` is a function handle, not a value-type. So when you perform the subtraction `y-g` in your `sum_res` function, there will be no subtraction operator that'll accept a function handle as an operand (how would you subtract a function handle?)

It looks like you simply forgot to pass your parameter `b` to your `g` function handle inside your `sum_res` function (assuming b is indeed your desired parameter)

```
sum_res = @(b)(y-g(b))'*(y-g(b));
```

Comment: Works perfectly: `x = randn(100,4);
y = randn(100,1);
g = @(b)((b(4).*(b(2).*x(:,1) + b(3).*x(:,2) + 1)) + b(5).*x(:,3).*x(:,4).^b(1));
sum_res = @(b)(y-g(b))'*(y-g(b));
[beta_opt,fval] = fminsearch(sum_res,[1,1,1,1,1]);`